# JavaFX FXML not responding to text input or Click (Events)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

I have  simple JavaFx project, with main class as eclipse JavaFx project default.

I have defined a controller , it looks like the skeleton generated by SceneBuilder, so everything is pretty much default.

When I run my application, In the UI I can't input data to the two textfields, or see the console output from my button event handlers.

A welcome.fxml file as shown below (deleted all other code to simplify)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <?import javafx.geometry.*?>
  <?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
  <?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
  <?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
  <?import javafx.scene.*?>
  <?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
  <?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
  <?import java.lang.*?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

  <Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mouseTransparent="true" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1100.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Welcome_Controller">
     <children>
        <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" depthTest="ENABLE" graphicTextGap="10.0" layoutX="496.0" layoutY="360.0" mouseTransparent="true" onAction="#OnSignInClick" opacity="0.82" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="109.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 100;" text="Sign In" textAlignment="CENTER" />
        <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="496.0" layoutY="409.0" mnemonicParsing="false" opacity="0.82" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="109.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 1000;" text="Sign Up" textAlignment="CENTER" />
        <Text fill="WHITE" layoutX="899.0" layoutY="702.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Copyright 2015, Dawood and Irtiza." />
        <TextField fx:id="tf_username" layoutX="427.0" layoutY="277.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="279.0" promptText="Enter new Username if you dont have an account " />
        <TextField fx:id="tf_password" layoutX="427.0" layoutY="312.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="279.0" promptText="Enter new password if you dont have an account" />
        <Label layoutX="355.0" layoutY="281.0" text="Username :" textFill="WHITE">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Label layoutX="355.0" layoutY="315.0" text="Password :" textFill="WHITE">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
     </children>
  </Pane>
```

Welcome_controller.java looks like a default skeleton generated by scene builder, code below

```
    package application;


    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;

    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Welcome_Controller implements Initializable {

        @FXML //  fx:id="btn_xxx"
        private Button btn_signin; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
        @FXML 
        private Button btn_signup;
        @FXML
        private TextField tf_username;
        @FXML
        private TextField tf_password;

        @Override // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
        public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources)
        {
            //assert btn_signin != null : "fx:id=\"btn_signin\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'welcome.fxml'.";
            //assert btn_signup != null : "fx:id=\"btn_signup\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'welcome.fxml'.";
            // initialize your logic here: all @FXML variables will have been injected
        }

        @FXML private void OnSignInClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
        {   
            System.out.println("clicked");
        }

        @FXML
        void OnSignupClick(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("clicked 2");

        }

    }
```

EDIT : This is the class with the main method.

package application;

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

    public class Main extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            try {
                Pane root = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("welcome.fxml"));
                Scene scene_1 = new Scene(root,1100,720);
                //scene_1.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                //we can set the different scenes when it need to
                primaryStage.setScene(scene_1);
                primaryStage.setTitle("Translate Messenger");
                primaryStage.show();

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("main may exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

When I run my application, In the UI I can't input data to the two textfields, or see the console output from my button event handlers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you run a JavaFX application, after the JavaFX event loop is started execution is passed (with an initial Stage) to a subclass of Application.  Does that code exist?

Comment: @scottb This is the default code I found in a few tutorials online, (I'm really new to Fx). I can't figure out whats missing

Comment: @scottb I have posted the main class now that extends javafx.application.Application .

Comment: Why are you laying everything out by hand, instead of using some kind of [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102)?

Comment: @James_D what benefit will that have? maybe I shouldnt have used scene builder. before creating the fx project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made the root pane transparent to the mouse with `mouseTransparent="true"`. This means that any mouse clicks on the root pane, or any of its descendent nodes (i.e. the whole UI) will be ignored. Consequently you cannot click the buttons or put focus on the text fields using the mouse. (Notice though you can navigate the UI using the tab key, and use the space key to generate a button click when it has the focus.)

Remove `mouseTransparent="true"` from the pane and from the "Sign In" button and it will work fine.

Comment: Scene builder defaults to mouseTransparent=true. I wasn't expecting problem in default fxml. Thankyou @James_D